# zIndex IE6/IE7 fix using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to code a popup but I ran into some problems when using z-index on the gray overlay for some reason in IE6 and IE7.

Is there a way to fix the z-index bug with jQuery in IE6/IE7 or is there some other way?

Please check jsfiddler http://jsfiddle.net/NrxbC/5/

Any help is much appreciated.

Best Regards
John

Comment: try with position absolute or relative (just for sake of testing) and see if z-index works then.

Comment: @ItayMoav Problem is that the overlay won't fill the whole window if I change it to absolute or relative.

Comment: Yes, I know, This is just to pin point the source of the problem.

Comment: @ItayMoav Same issue there when changing to position absolute and relative, it overlaps everything on the screen.

Comment: Actually, the overlay SHOULD be on the entire screen. Are u saying it also covers the popup contents? Give more details, as most of us do not have IE7 and certainly not 6 anymore

Comment: @ItayMoav There's a full screen overlay with opacity which should be layered above everything except the popup window.

Comment: The proper way to do lightbox (which is what you try, it to have the content html elements as childs of the overlay (inside it). But what most developers will do is simply take an exisiting system, like colorbox, and re style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not using an open source like colorbox or fancybox or lightbox ..

(i can't comment for moment)

Comment: I prefer having full control of my scripts if I were to do some major changes :/

Comment: @john: redo the example of the overlay without jquery (as opened state) to be sure // 
the problem is in your css

Comment: I did thanks! i added the overlay div right before the popup window instead of adding it at the end of the body, which works!

Answer (score 1):

On `IE7` you can solve removing temporarily the `filter` property just before the fadeIn and then re-applying later

```
$(el).css("filter", "").fadeIn(200, function () {
    $(el).css("display","inline-block;").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=65)");
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/NrxbC/11/

Comment: The gray overlay still layers above the popup box though so that doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Put an higher value for z-index in the parent div... eg,

```
<div id="parent" style="z-index:2002">
<div id="child" style="z-index:2000">// The actual div which needs the z-index
</div>
</div>
```

also refer [this page](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/),

It may look silly... but it works...

Comment: This does seem to work but it's hell of ugly fix? would there be a way to do this through jQuery?

Comment: try giving position:relative with all the z-index values... eg: .popupdiv {position:relative; z-index:9002;}